# is it ok to precreate dialog in android?

Tags: android

I have several cases in my application where I create and show alertdialog wiht different xml layouts using DialogBuilder.

Most of my dialogs are simple - containig just a timepicker or numberpicker etc.
They are created and shown fast.

But one of the dialogs contains MapView.
and building and showing is deffinitelly slower  than others.
I guess it's because the map.

so I wonder if it is a good practice in android ro precreate the dialog right after activity creation and later I just show it.

thanks in advance

------ EDIT - added source code -------

Everytime when I tap an element on the layout I create the corresponding dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_XXXX, null);
builder.setView(view);
.....
.....
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
builder.show();

mActivity.showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.loading));
```

and here for the dialog with the mapview I have the following:

```
final MapView mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
mapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      mGoogleMap = googleMap;
      mGoogleMap.setMinZoomPreference(12);                            
      mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);                            
      mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(xxxx,yyyyy));
      mActivity.hideProgressDialog();
   }
});
```

and there is a delay before the dialog with the mapview is shown.
and the progressdialog I try to show in the meantime is not shown at all.

So I wonder what if I pre-create the dialog right after activity creation and 
assign it to a member variable (mDialog):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_XXXX, null);
builder.setView(view);
.....
.....
mDialog = builder.create();
```

And then on UI click just to show the pre-created dialog:
    mDialog.show();

But I wonder is it a good practice.
Is there a reason not to pre-create dialogs and store the instances in member variables of the activity (or fragment) and just show them later when needed.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to preCreate a Drawable?

Comment: I've edited my question and added explanations and source code

Comment: mapView.getMapAsync() is the call that takes a while. If your going the direction of getting the dialog ready upon activity creation, I would recommend just inflating the dialog layout and getting the map ready. Then when you need it just set the dialog view and it shouldn't have to do any extra work.

Comment: thanks. I'll try this. And what about the progress dialog. do you have any idea why I dont see it during the getMapAsync call? Because if thre ia a delay before the dialog is shown I want to inform the user that something is on instead of just having unresponsive ui.  -  user clicks and nothing hapens fir 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just make sure that pre-creating your dialog won't slow down your activity creation.